# JSON - how to parse it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I just got a problem about this response. Supposedly if I want to choose item from the response it must be an array value.

```
"telegraphicTransferBankMap": {
        "BOA BEJ, JKT": "0330301",
        "BPD KALBAR SYARIAH, PTK": "1239922",
        "ANDARA, DPSR": "4660019",
        "GANESHA HAYAM WURUK, JKT": "1610017",
...
}
```

Actually must be like this one right? (let me know if I'm mistaken)

```
"telegraphicTransferBankMap": [
            {"BOA BEJ, JKT": "0330301"},
            {"BPD KALBAR SYARIAH, PTK": "1239922"},
            {"ANDARA, DPSR": "4660019"},
            {"GANESHA HAYAM WURUK, JKT": "1610017"},
    ...
    ]
```

My code:

```
var ul = $('#telegraphicTransferBankMap');
    var html ='';
    for (var key in telegraphicTransferBankMap) {
        if (telegraphicTransferBankMap.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            telegraphicTransferBankMapItem = telegraphicTransferBankMap[key];
            html += '<option value="'+telegraphicTransferBankMapItem.xxxxxx+'">'+telegraphicTransferBankMapItem.yyyyyyy+'</option>';
        }
    }
    ul.append(html);
```

Then I want to put telegraphicTransferBankMapItem.xxxxxx as bankId and telegraphicTransferBankMapItem.yyyyyyy as bankName.

Comment: You're mistaken. The first JSON is correct. The second one is not value JSON. Although the first one is also not completely correct. It should be surrounded by `{` and `}`.

Comment: I already fixed the question. so how I can parse it?

Comment: in addition to @koenpeters comment that i should be surrounde by {} then replace your current {} with []

Comment: They are both fine as long as it's inside an object, but neither is JSON, they are both just plain javascript objects and arrays.

Comment: @adeneo to be more precise: it's an automatically instantiated object written in a JSON syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your first json and change your loop like,

```
var telegraphicTransferBankMap = {
    "BOA BEJ, JKT": "0330301",
    "BPD KALBAR SYARIAH, PTK": "1239922",
    "ANDARA, DPSR": "4660019",
    "GANESHA HAYAM WURUK, JKT": "1610017",
}

for (var key in telegraphicTransferBankMap) {
    if (telegraphicTransferBankMap.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        bank = telegraphicTransferBankMap[key];
        html += '<option value="' + bank + '">' + key + '</option>';
    }
}
```

<kbd>[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/02qt9hxd/)</kbd>

Also you should bank-id as key in your json rather than of bank name.

Answer (score 0):

As of your code here:

```
  if (telegraphicTransferBankMap.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        telegraphicTransferBankMapItem = telegraphicTransferBankMap[key];
```

an object like your first definition is expected - and sufficient

To add that to the option list just do

```
   html += '<option value="'+key+'">'+telegraphicTransferBankMapItem+'</option>';
```